# Does 1Vac matters to a Arduino pin?

Tags: arduino, dc, ac

I am planning to do a current measurement with Arduino. The board I'm using is mega 2650, operating voltage is 5V (I/O pin limit is 3.3V). And the CT I'm using is exactly the same as this [tutorial](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks/ct-sensors-interface), the only difference is that the output of the CT is limited to 0-1Vac.

Now, I'm thinking if it is possible to directly connect the CT to the Arduino board? What would be the outcome if I connect a AC voltage source to it?

Moreover, if direct connection is not possible, then a simple bridge diode could turn AC to DC. But again, a ripple signal will be resulted and with a measuring current of 0-100A ac and output signal of 0-1Vac ( meaning 1A ac measured current only result in 0.01Vac). What would be the resulted accuracy? Best if could archive measuring accuracy to +-0.1Aac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. The 1VAC signal will then be between 2 an 3v so the arduino wont have a problem reading it in.

edit: The resistor should be around 1k - 10k

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5p8q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: C1 in this circuit should be bipolar (not electrolytic).

Comment: Just want to ask, the signal output will be with a range of 1.5 - 3.5V? Am I getting this right?

Comment: The new "ground" for the signal will be in this case 2.5V.

Answer (score 0):

Diode is very bad idea. Most diodes have 0.6-0.7V voltage drop, so your current measurement will be impossible in such small range. In addition - that voltage drop is not constant.

You have to stick with method shown in tutorial.

Adding 2.5V to input voltage in analog part is very common and good method.

Negative voltages in microcontroller are not welcome, all negative signal will be shorted into ground by ESD protection diode until it blows up.