# Reduce analog reading noise on arduino

Tags: arduino, current-measurement

[With refer to this question:](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107639/does-1vac-matters-to-a-arduino-pin)

I got CTs connected to all analog pins on a Arduino Mega, connections for each pins are as mentioned [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107639/does-1vac-matters-to-a-arduino-pin).

Readings were good indoors, +- 0.1A. However, when located outdoors, even without connecting any CTs/ connected to a CT(but the CT is not clamped onto any wires), readings are detected, ranging from **0.1A to 2A**.

I am using a CT for 50A range measurement and the output signal is 1Vac.

The IOREF pin is linked to the Vin pin on the Arduino board.

1. I have tried to make more accurate readings (hoping to achieve at least +-0.1A) from programming as in [here](http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/making-accurate-adc-readings-on-arduino), and [here](https://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/SecretVoltmeter). Doesn't make much difference though...
2. I have used a non-polarized capacitor in my circuit. I was thinking if that cause the noise? But I thought polarized/non-polarized capacitor does not matter in this case?
3. Would a ferrite bead on the CT be helpful? Or in other terms, the connecting wires needed to be shielded? The wires are only for transmitting a voltage back to the analog pins, how could noise enter the wire?
4. Lastly, I actually got the [circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107639/does-1vac-matters-to-a-arduino-pin) on a pcb. The grid are 0.5mm. So...poor PCB design? i.e. traces too close to each other?

   [image]

Comment: Is there a pull down or pull up resistor on the analog sense lines?

Comment: Also, the answer to 2,3,4 are basically "No" especially 2 and 4, these are not issues.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "pull up resistor on the analog sense lines"?

Comment: You are getting false readings when nothing is connected. That is usually because your inputs a floating. It is a good idea to have a high resistance pulling to 0V or to VCC. It also depends on the way the input signal is created, if it is a simple voltage divider then these resistors may be loaded/affected. I have not looked at your schematics/circuit links yet so this is just general advice.

Comment: Yes it seems you have put a 2.5V DC bias on the inputs, so an extra 50k-100K pull down resistor will be a reasonable addition to reduce noise. Try it.

Comment: Great! I'll try and update later!